# How block on File Choose Dialog or get the Upload Button Event?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

```
    function importcsv(arg) {
    $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    var fileVal=document.getElementById("upload");
    var filePath = fileVal.value;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var result ="";       
    fr.readAsText(fileVal.files[0]);    
    fr.onload = function(e) {
        result=e.target.result;
        post("worker.php?arg="+arg,result);
    };  
    return true;
}
```

why this is only on second clic, choose and up file? first call the filePath var is empty...how i can block until file is choosen?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you put your trigger at the very first line. Move that to the last position like :

```
function importcsv(arg) {
    var fileVal=document.getElementById("upload");
    var filePath = fileVal.value;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var result ="";       
    fr.readAsText(fileVal.files[0]);    
    fr.onload = function(e) {
        result=e.target.result;
        post("worker.php?arg="+arg,result);
    };  
    $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: then it doesnt open a file chooser Dialog and give me a js console error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');  
//i need to block here until file is choosen
var fileVal=document.getElementById("upload");
alert(fileVal.value);